# TCL incr gives wrong value for zero padded integer

Tags: tcl, increment

I was trying to increment a number which is padded by zeroes to become a six digit number. But strangely any value other than single digit gives a wrong value. like

```
set x 000660
incr x 1
```

gives result 433. Also tried with smaller number like 010 but the result is 9. Why is this happening ?
What is the proper way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers beginning with `0` like

```
000660
```

are octet integers. It's equivalent to decimal `432`.

The same for `010` (the same as `8` in decimal)

---

To strip off zeros, try this:

```
proc stripzeros {value} {
    regsub ^0+(.+) $value \\1 retval
    return $retval
}
```

For more information, see [Tcl FAQ: How can I use numbers with leading zeroes?](http://psg.com/~joem/tcl/faq.html#LeadingZeros).

Comment: How can i stop tcl from treating it as octate

Comment: @Codename_DJ Is removing the leading `0`s an option?

Comment: That is the most obvious path I have. But is not there any identifier or something to denote it as integer forcefully ?

Comment: @Codename_DJ I don't think so. Any way, check out the link I just added, hope it's useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way too.

```
 proc getIntVal { x } { 
        # Using 'scan' command to get the literal integer value
        set count [ scan $x %d n ]
        if { $count!= 1 } { 
            return -1
        }   
        return $n
    }

proc padZero { x } {
    # Using 'format' to pad with leading zeroes. 
    return [ format "%05d" $x ]
}

set val 00060 
puts "Initial value : $val"

set tmp [ getIntVal $val ]; # 'tmp' will have the value as '60'

incr tmp; 

set val [ padZero $tmp ]; # Padding with zero now

puts "Final value : $val"
```

Comment: @glennjackman Is it a good thing if the `val` is not a numeric string and the code extracts the numeric part and proceeds with the processing? From my POV, having input `val` of 123abc` and output of 124 after `incr` just seems wrong.

Comment: One strategy is to: `set count [scan $x %d%s n rest]` and handle the cases where count is 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: @glennjackman Often, `%d%c` works better. This is because it will handle trailing spaces by failing, whereas `%s` won't cause a failure. (OTOH, when Tcl parses a number, it strips spaces from it — I just checked — so `%d%s` might be the right thing to do after all…)

Answer (score 1):

Yu Hao already explained the problem of octets, and Dinesh added some procs to circumvent the issue. I am suggesting creating one proc that will take on a zero padded integer and return another zero padded integer of the same format and which should work just like `incr`:

```
proc incr_pad {val args} {
  # Check if increment is given properly
  if {[llength $args] == 0} {
    set args 1
  } elseif {[llength $args] > 1} {
    return -code error {wrong # args: should be "incr_pad varName ?increment?"}
  }

  # Check for integers
  if {![regexp {^[0-9]+$} $val]} {
    return -code error "expected integer but got \"$val\""
  } elseif {![regexp {^[0-9]+$} $args]} {
    return -code error "expected integer but got \"$args\""
  }

  # Get number of digits
  set d [regexp -all {[0-9]} $val]

  # Trim 0s to the left
  set newval [string trimleft $val 0]

  # Now use incr
  incr newval $args

  # Return back the number formatted with the same zero padding as initially given
  return [format "%0${d}d" $newval]
}
```

With this...

```
% incr_pad 000660 1
000661
% incr_pad 2.5 1
expected integer but got "2.5"
% incr_pad 02 1.5
expected integer but got "1.5"
% incr_pad 010 2
012
% incr_pad 1 2 3
wrong # args: should be "incr_pad varName ?increment?"
% incr_pad 00024
00025
% incr_pad 999
1000
```

Of course, you can change the name of the function to a shorter one or one which you find more appropriate.